# Power steering pump is whining and has foamy orange stuff

Tags: power-steering

I have a 2004 Honda Accord. It is foaming orange stuff. The fluid should be clear?? Took it to a shop, they flushed the system, said they had to do it 3 times, said there were no leaks in the lines and the pump was working fine. Said they got most of the orange stuff out, but theres still a tinge of it, but its mostly clear again. Felt better driving it after the flush. Started it up this morning, made the same whining noise as before, worse when you move wheel back and forth. Looked in the reservior, orange and foaming again. Sigh. Any ideas??

Comment: ADD 1/3 cup of ATF Dextron only is a cure I found during my research

Answer (score 10):

The 'foaming' you describe is almost certainly air getting into the system. The power steering pump will cause a suction effect in the pump and then pressurise the system. Look for loose hose clips, damaged piping, and leaking seals on the pump body between the pump and its fluid reservoir.

Comment: I just had the system flushed and checked, shop said they didn't detect any leaks, cracks, etc any where in the system. Why did the fluid turn orange?

Comment: @leesa You have a leak, no question. A hose can suck air in and not leak fluid out. Take it back to the shop that inspected it before.

Comment: Or, if the failed to find the leak, it might be better idea to take it to a different shop.

Answer (score 0):

What usually gets overlooked is the Rack and pinion as they are notorious for failing and allowing air to come in through worn seals.

Comment: Is this a comment regarding rack-and-pinion setups in general or is this specific to this model of Accord? Worth clarifying...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same after I flushed it myself.  The Honda dealer told me that I need a new pump which I could not believe.  It worked fine before I changed the fluid.

I noticed that the level in the reservoir is below the return line.  I think that the air must come in due to that.  I added more fluid and let it stand over night to allow the foam to turn into liquid again.
Before I turned on the engine I turned the wheels about 5 time left to right.  Some air bubbles came out.  After that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

agree with Allan but will add many times I have see air can also be entering at the actual pump from a bad steering pump seal so add this to your inspection. That color reminds me of a power steering stop leak product added.